# Хелп с блоком в css

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, есть форма поиска на ajax, выводит информацию из базы все как положено, и для вывода инфы идет такой код

```
 if (mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
     echo "<div class='search'>";
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
         echo $row['name']."<br />";
     }
     echo "</div>";
 }
```

и css класса search:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 13px;
-moz-border-radius: 13px;
border-radius: 13px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #7B68EE;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #7B68EE;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px #7B68EE;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
color: #888888;
margin-left:10px;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

И когда вывожу инфу, весь сайт двигается вниз, то есть освобождает место для результата поиска, как сделать что бы сайт не куда не двигался а выводил результат прям поверх всего типа окошечка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в **css класса search:** добавить

```
position:fixed;
/*либо в зависимости от предпочтений*/
position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

сделайте блок абсолютно позицированным и с большим значением z-index